# How URL doesn't change in different action related to one page in Asp.Net Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For example, there is a Member Controller with two actions:

1-Show : Display list of member with tag  in front of each member to delete related Member from database.

2-Delete: To Delete Member from database

Tag "a" to delete:

```
<a href="/Member/Delete/Id">Delete<a>
```

When Delete Clicked the URL address changed to /Member/Delete/Id. I don't want URL change and remain /Member/Show, **although I want to show a success message when member deleted**.

What is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely should **not** be deleting or making other destructive changes using a HTTP GET request. Make the delete action HTTP POST and have a form that submits to the controller with the ID for deletion. The submit button easily could be styled to look like a link if you require to fit an existing design.

In terms of your requirement, I would actually make the delete form submit using AJAX and in the success callback return your message and remove the item from the page. This will not require reloading the page at all and will be straightforward to achieve with jQuery.

Alternatively, if you are not confident with JavaScript or do not want to use Ajax requests, you could return a [Redirect to Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505283%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) result from the POST request which returns you to the list, and adds the deleted item Id to the Route Value Dictionary for the action.

For this to work it should match a defined nullable int parameter on your action. This could then be set on your view model when binding, or you could simply use ViewBag. Then in the view you could do something like this-

```
@if (Model.ItemDeleted.HasValue) {
   <p class="success-message">Successfully deleted item @Model.ItemDeleted.Value</p>
}
```